# How to deal with the error that Nusmv cannot check ctl properties with input variables (IVAR)?

Tags: nusmv, ctl

**MODULE** 
main

**IVAR**
v1 ：boolean;

**VAR**
v2 : boolean;

**SPEC NAME**
p1 := AG (v1&v2);

**file ltlerror.smv: line 8: Property contains input variables:**

Comment: Please add some context and tell us what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At pages 24-25 of [NuSMV 2.6 user manual](http://nusmv.fbk.eu/NuSMV/userman/v26/nusmv.pdf), it's written:

> [...] input variables cannot occur in:
>
> [...]
>
> - Some specification kinds: CTLSPEC, SPEC, INVARSPEC, COMPUTE, PSLSPEC.
>     For example:
>
>   ```
>   IVAR i : boolean;
>   VAR s : boolean;
>   SPEC AF (i -> s) – this is NOT allowed 
>   LTLSPEC F (X i -> s) – this is allowed
>   ```

---

Workarounds:

1. use `LTL`:

   ```
   MODULE main
   IVAR
     v1 : boolean;
   VAR
     v2 : boolean;

   LTLSPEC NAME p1 := G (v1 & v2);
   ```
2. Declare `v1` as a normal variable, but use it as an input variable. To do this, do not impose any constraint on the initial and future values of `v1`, i.e. do not write `init(v1) :=` or `next(v1) :=` or equivalent constraints.